Watertight sealant that can still be undone years later
How can I seal a plumbing joint water-tight and still expect to undo it in a few years time?
5 years ago I replaced a water heater tank with a new one with a 7 year guarantee. The heating element only had a 3 year guarantee, and failed recently. When fitted, the original plumber smeared the thread on the heater element with liberal quantities of what was probably either boss white or plumbers mait.
After five years of gentle cooking, the joint became rock-solid and the plumber who tried to remove it ended up damaging the water tank itself.
The original plumber is long-gone. The current plumber blames the old plumber, and the guarantee for the water tank doesn't cover mechanical damage, so ignoring for the moment the issue of responsibility, how can I ensure that the new heating element in the new tank can be replaced easily in another few years time? I'm looking for a sealant that will make a joint water-tight without acting as a glue or bonding agent. Many sealants are advertised as 'non-setting' which is probably a good thing, but after several years even the best putties seem to set hard.

Unless the joint requires a paste type sealant, teflon/plumbing tape is a good choice if wrap on right.

If you are speaking of a new electric tank, the heating elements come already fitted in all new tanks I have ever seen. What you found on the threads was probably minerals from the water.  You cannot blame this issue on the past plumber.
That said, when I change elements I put no sealer on the threads. There is a rubber seal that works very well to stop any leaks between the element and the tank. The threads are also the elements bond to ground. Applying a sealer could interfere with the element grounding properly.
